# Hardcoded value or external property takes precedence for DB pool size?

Tags: spring, database, spring-boot

I have the below configuration in my springboot code :

```
xaDataSource.setMaxPoolSize(50);
```

Also I have this in the application.properties

```
data-source.reference.maximumPoolSize=15
```

Which one takes precendence?

Comment: That depends on your creation of the bean.

Comment: Where exactly are you calling `xaDataSource.setMaxPoolSize(50);`?

Comment: in a DB @Configuration class